# How to do ewm_mean in rust polars?

Tags: python, rust, python-polars, rust-polars

In python we can do:

```
df.with_columns([
   pl.col("myCol").ewm_mean(50)
])
```

But how do we do the same in rust?  The following doesn't work:

```
df.with_columns([
    col("myCol").ewm_mean(50)
])
```

It fails with `No method named ewm_mean found in Expr`.

While polars is great, the documentation for Rust is awful!  I've tried searching to documentation, and all I can find is polars_arrow::kernels::ewm, but there is no human text in that area of the documentation.  I've also tried looking at the python source to see if I can work down and figure out what it is doing but I can't trace it further back into PyExpr.

(I expect the 50 won't work either - I'm anticipating having to pass some sort of EWMOptions struct in the rust one, and have to calculate alpha rather than com.  The python source that I can understand seems to calculate alpha first before switching to PyExpr)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out the above code will run, but it requires the `ewma` feature in the cargo.toml

Comment: What polars version are you using? Do you have to add emwa feature in cargo.toml to polars-arrow or polars-lazy?